# Reference.cs is empty when generating service client

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to setup a VS2010 project in VS2012 and have a problem with generating the service references. Somewhere it fails and Reference.cs becomes empty.

I looked at this:
[WCF Service Reference generates an empty reference.cs due to DuplexBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224525/wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs-due-to-duplexbinding) 
But since the code is working for VS2010 I would prefer not to change anything.

I have tried this: 
[Sometimes adding a WCF Service Reference generates an empty reference.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs)

Then it appears code in Reference.cs but some functions is missing so the project doesn´t work. Is there any known problems when doing this? I am totally stuck and need some ideas.

Thanks in advance! 
/David

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sometimes adding a WCF Service Reference generates an empty reference.cs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408509/sometimes-adding-a-wcf-service-reference-generates-an-empty-reference-cs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Add Service Reference dialog , click on 'Advanced', there uncheck the option 'Reuse reference types in this assembly'

[image]

I often encounter this problem, this workaround works most of the times.